# How the App Intent Vocabulary Property List works?

Tags: ios, swift, siri

I have implemented all **five** intents for workout: *start, pause, resume, cancel, end*.

They basically works with phrase:

*Start my workout using MyApp*

But here I need to replace phrase `workout` with `service`... so I have added `App Intent Vocabulary Property List` to the project like this:

[image]

I assume that thanks to this, I can call Siri like this:

*Start my service using MyApp*

...and it works like a charm. But works for every five intents. Shouldn't it work only for **Start Workout**?

Intent Phrases are for Siri guide, and it also works:

[image]
[image]

Let me understand it well, this *.plist* is only to replace default `workout` keyword and to setup guide for Siri, right?